# Can I add custom UIView to ORKStep in ResearchKit

Tags: ios, researchkit

Currently I'm working with `ResearchKit`. In a `ORKTaskViewController` I'd like to show my custom view embedded in some specified tasks. How can I achieve this can someone provide me with a sample code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest you post a issue on rk's github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small example on `ORKTest` which uses the `customView` property of the `ORKActiveStepView` controller. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/Testing/ORKTest/ORKTest/MainViewController.m#L3379-L3418).

And the documentation for that property is [here](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/7f106898e23dd00057dc08a77591913f851f6bd7/ResearchKit/ActiveTasks/ORKActiveStepViewController.h#L72-L82).

Hope that helps.